# Drupal: Redirecting/Changing the front page from a module

Tags: drupal, redirect, module

I am creating a module which will allow a 'viral launch' of a website. So before it has launched, you turn this module on and all non-registered users are sent to the 'Get an Invite' page where they enter their email address and then get put on a mailing list. They get given a link to share and once they have referred enough people, they get an invite.

So far I've got the page setup and I can change where the link to it appears in the menu system, but what I really want is to pickup non-registered/anonymous users and redirect them to the Get an Invite page instead of the default /node page.

How do I do this?

Comment: try using the rules module you can set it in a way which should help you out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using Drupal 7 or Drupal 6, but vishal may be offering the best solution short of writing a custom module with a drupal_goto() function call for anonymous users attempting to get anywhere but the "Get an invite" (or perhaps "/user" page for a login, if that page does not include a login form.

Use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to create a new rule where, if a user with the role "Anonymous user" attempts to access content, they are redirected to the "Get an invite" page. The latest dev version of Rules (for Drupal 7) should be able to manage this task for you (I've just tested it) and the D6 version may be even more stable for this kind of job. Then, instead of deactivating a module (e.g. a custom access module like what you describe), you would simply make the rule inactive or remove the rule.

[Drupal’s Content Access module](http://drupal.org/project/content_access), which also includes a Rules integration component, might also be helpful for your use case.